# Date filter and input box for relative date using spotfire

Tags: python, date, ironpython, spotfire

Can someone help me create something that allow me to select relative time periods (input box with last 7, 14, 30 days) AND an ability to select specific date ranges using the date filter in SPOTFIRE ?

I have idea but looks like I need to write a python script. No experience there. Appreciate any help.

What I probably wanna do is:

Write a script that updates whenever your input box gets updated. The script you first check to see if the value is 0 or null (depending on which you choose). If it is, it would delete the data limiting expression for the visualization. If the input box has a valid value in it then it would need to (a) reset the date filter so all values are selected and (b) set the data limiting expression for the visualization to `[Date] > Max(DateAdd(‘dd’, -${p.NumberOfDays}, [Date]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the technique detailed here: 
https://community.tibco.com/questions/calculated-date-filters

I created a drop down list control in the text area, named the property NextNDays and set the Expressions =

```
For next 30 days:
Display Name = "Next 30 Days"
Expression = "If(DateDiff('day',DateTimeNow(),[MY_DATE_FIELD]) < 31 and [MY_DATE_FIELD] > DateTimeNow(),True)"

For next 60 days:
Display Name = "Next 60 Days"<
Expression = "If(DateDiff('day',DateTimeNow(),[MY_DATE_FIELD]) < 61 and [MY_DATE_FIELD] > DateTimeNow(),True)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the share. This helps to an extent. But I would like my date filter to work too. In this case only the drop-down works not the date filter. When my drop-down is not selected I would like my date filter to work.

Comment: I added an "All" option with the expression = true and it is selected by default.  When "All" is selected the date filter (I'm using the sliders) work.  My understanding is the filters are applied to the data after the "limit by expression".

Answer (score 1):

Careful on asking [XY Problems](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem) but in your case you could just use this expression in the [Limit Data Using Expression](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_details_on_limit_data_using_expression.htm) box of what ever visualization want to be affected.

```
[Date] >= DateAdd('dd', ${p.NumberOfDays} * -1, [Date])
AND
[Date] < DateTimeNow()
```

Note, if `[Date]` is a DateTime type, you need to cast it as a date to eliminate you missing partial dates.

```
[Date] >= DateAdd('dd', ${p.NumberOfDays} * -1, Cast([Date] as Date))
AND
Cast([Date] as Date) <= Cast(DateTimeNow() as Date)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. I tried your expression in the Limit data section but din't work. I am able to filter using the date filter but when I enter a value in the input box, the result are still filtered based on the Date Filter and not based on the value in the input box.

Comment: What didn't work about it? Did the expression return an error? In order for this expression to work, you'd want to NOT use the date filter. Otherwise, you'll have conflicting filtering cases. For example, it would be like using two date filters and setting them to different criteria. The analytic wouldn't know which to use. So, set the date filter to include ALL dates, and then let the analytic be filtered base on the ${p.NumberOfDays} entered

Comment: It's not throwing an error. When I enter a value in the input box, the viz is not filtered by this input box value.

Comment: is that really your doc property name?

Comment: Yep it is (${p.NumberOfDays} )